# Is it possible to use the Magic trackpad on Windows?

Tags: windows, compatibility, magic-trackpad

Is this possible to use the Apple Magic Trackpad on a Windows Computer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bootcamp FAQ is helpful for these sorts of questions

- http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/
- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4273